# How do I know whether its save to access a Fragment's ChildFragmentManager any longer?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I stumble upon the dreaded `Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` exception when I'm trying to put something in the fragment's child fragment manager.

How can I properly know that I should not do that? I read through `FragmentManager`s and `Fragment`s code and couldn't see any flag that is flipped after `onSaveInstanceState()` was called on the fragment.

Surely, I could do `FragmentTransaction.commitAllowStateLoss()` but this is a dirty hack and having a boolean flag that I toggle when I override the fragment's `onSaveInstanceState` method is also ugly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule I use for committing a `FragmentTransaction` is:

- It's safe to do it in `onActivityCreated`
- It's safe to do it when the `isResumed` is `true`

You can find a more in depth article about what happens [here.](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) The  recommendations for not getting the exception are:

- Be careful when committing transactions inside Activity lifecycle methods.
- Avoid performing transactions inside asynchronous callback methods.
- Use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` only as a last resort.

Comment: Checking for paused state seems plausible, will try that, thanks!